# Dynamic C string (char*) weird behavior

Tags: c, string, malloc

I got 2 functions:
- `stringCopy()` which copy the parameter `strToCopy` into another string dynamically allocated applying a sanitize (see 2nd function)
- `_sanitized()` which returns a dynamically allocated uppercased version of the parameter and removing non-letters char (such as numeric values & spaces).

Considering the following, I got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because of `k` growing too much.

```
char* _sanitized(const char* str)
{
    char* uppercasedStr = malloc(sizeof str);

    int k = 0; // Index de parcours de la chaîne originale
    int i = k; // Index dans la nouvelle chaîne
    char evaluatedChar;
    while ( (evaluatedChar = str[k]) != '\0') 
    {
        if ('A' <= evaluatedChar && evaluatedChar <= 'Z') 
        {
            uppercasedStr[i] = evaluatedChar;
            i++;
        }
        else if ('a' <= evaluatedChar && evaluatedChar <= 'z') 
        {
            uppercasedStr[i] = evaluatedChar-32;
            i++;
        }

        k++;
    }
    i++;
    uppercasedStr[i] = '\0';

    return uppercasedStr;
}


char* stringCopy(char* strToCopy)
{
    char* uppercaseStr = _sanitized(strToCopy);

    char* copiedStr = malloc(sizeof uppercaseStr);

    int k = 0;
    while (uppercaseStr[k] != '\0') 
    {
        copiedStr[k] = uppercaseStr[k];
        k++;
    }
    k++;
    copiedStr[k] = '\0';

    free(uppercaseStr);

    return copiedStr;
}
```

I also noticed that when I copy char from `uppercaseStr` into `copiedStr` it modifies `uppercaseStr` in the same time which cause the overflow...

Comment: shouldn't `malloc(sizeof str)` be `malloc(strlen(str))` ?

Comment: @Neel Basu in that case, use strlen(str) + 1

Comment: Everybody repeat after me: sizeof != strlen

Comment: Shouldn't identifiers with leading underscores be reserved for the implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The error I see is here:**

```
char* uppercasedStr = malloc(sizeof str);
```

You can't use `sizeof()` to get the length of a string. You need to use `strlen()`:

```
char* uppercasedStr = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);  //  Need +1 for terminating null
```

**Here's the other occurrence of the same mistake:**

```
char* copiedStr = malloc(sizeof uppercaseStr);
```

should be:

```
char* copiedStr = malloc(strlen(uppercaseStr) + 1);
```

`sizeof(str)` only gives you the size of a `char` pointer, not the length of the entire c-string.

Also note that I omitted the `sizeof(char)`. This is because `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 in C. Therefore it is not needed.

Comment: Right.  `sizeof str` gives you the size of the pointer, not anything related to the length of the string.